# Getting Active: active (exited) status on code deploy agent aws

Tags: 18.04, services, aws, aptdaemon, continuous-deployment

I installed CodeDeploy Agent on my Ubuntu server.

Output of `sudo service codedeploy-agent status`:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-07-20 18:16:37 UTC; 4s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4968 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/codedeploy-agent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

How to change `active(exited)` to `active(running)`?

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer here https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/228

```
sudo rm /opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/codedeploy-agent.pid
sudo rm /opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/codedeploy-agent.pid.lock
sudo service codedeploy-agent restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sudo service codedeploy-agent restart` to change the active status to `active(running)`

Then verify the active status is running with `sudo service codedeploy-agent status`.

I had the same thing happen to me around the same time and it hasn't happened since.